# Why is Regex.Replace giving me weird result for last group

Tags: c#, regex

A simple example:

```
Regex.Replace("12345678910999999999", @"(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2})", "$1-$2-$3 $4")
```

This outputs to:

```
123-456-789 10999999999
```

But why? I have specifically set the group index i need. And that group index contains the exact value (checked in debugger).

Here is a fiddle:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/dkAPx3

Comment: What do you expect? Truncate the rest of digits? Match them, `@"^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2}).*"`

Comment: You're only replacing the text that matches. All the 9's at the end aren't modified by the replace, they carry over.

Comment: I was expecting only 2 digits as the last group. In this case: 123-456-789 10. The fiddle contains the expected line in output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Match the rest of the string with `.*` to truncate it:

```
Regex.Replace("12345678910999999999", @"^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2}).*", "$1-$2-$3 $4")
```

I'd also add `^` at the start to match the beginning of the string.

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28%5Cd%7B3%7D%29%28%5Cd%7B3%7D%29%28%5Cd%7B3%7D%29%28%5Cd%7B2%7D%29.*&i=12345678910999999999&r=%241-%242-%243%20%244).

Comment: Wow. I get it now. Regex had to consume them so they are not output to replace.

Answer (score 4):

Your regex has matched and replaced only "first" part of string, add `.*` to the end of the pattern:

```
Regex.Replace("12345678910999999999", @"(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2}).*", "$1-$2-$3 $4"); // results in "123-456-789 10"
```